# Web Facebook Login Button Opens Blank Facebook Page When Clicked Inside iOS Safari View Controller

Tags: ios, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.x, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have an iOS app I am developing that uses a Safari View Controller to open my website via the app.  On the home page of my app I have implemented the Facebook SDK Login Button and everything works fine, I get logged in via Facebook and them and redirected to my website and am logged in.

On that website I have a web Facebook login button.  Everything works fine when the site is accessed via Safari directly, but if I go through the app and click the Facebook login button on my site, the Safari View controller opens a blank web page that is on a facebook URL and the problem is that no content is ever displayed.